# How to give users acces to some other home directories

Tags: permissions, filesystems, users, ftp, vsftpd

I'm configuring GNU/Linux users as users for a vsftpd FTP server and I have the following safety constraints:

- User *foo* can read and write in his home directory.
- User *bar* can read and write in his home directory and in *foo*'s.
- User *baz* can read and write in his and *foo*'s and read in *bar*'s home directory.
- All users must not read any other directory (users are in a *chroot jail* by the `vsftp.conf`).

How would I achieve something like this?

Comment: You can't do that as described. Which bits are negotiable?

Comment: could you explain why this can't be done (I believe you, just to understand it). The most important part would be, that the users can only access some directories.

Comment: If you put the users each in their own chroot they can't access anything else. Period. If that's negotiable then the rest can be easily solved.

Comment: ok, I see. Is there another method to make sure the users can acces the directories as described above but nothing else?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use ACL (access control lists) in this case.  It allows much more finegrained control than just user/group permissions.

See https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-acls-on-linux for an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, either you open the rights of the specific folders like 660

Either each of them belong to a specific group that can access to specific folders
example :
if folder2 belongs to apache
you can do a usermod -a -G apache bar to allow him to access to this folder
but at this moment you have to double-check if it's not too much permissive

Maybe you can do intermediary groups to access to some folders, but I'm not sure that it's a good idea to manipulate the rights of what is in /home/
Better to use a network share mount point or a shared folder somewhere else in the filesystem, in my opinion